# Every set and sub-set of 4 unique objects from a list of 30 objects?

Tags: java, pseudocode

I'm having trouble making an **algorithm that produces every set and sub-set (including the empty set) from a list of ~30 objects**, with a maximum of 4 objects in each set.

I'm making it in Java, but pseudo-code should be fine.

This is what I've done so far:

```
for (int a = 0; a < Objects.length; a++) {
    for (int b = a + 1; b < Objects.length; b++) {
        for (int c = b + 1; c < Objects.length; c++) {
            for (int d = c + 1; d < Objects.length; d++) {
                // add Objects[a, b, c, d] to the Set
                // do other stuff
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But clearly this does not work, as it forces 4 objects in every set (whilst I need the sub-sets with less elements).

Googling this problem produces a lot of answers, but never one which produces all sub-sets AND where there's a limit on the set's size.

Comment: Your question doesn't match the description. Every **4** unique objects, but description sounds like you want also every 3,2 and 1 unique objects too?

Comment: @weston true, will try to edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
// add the empty set []
for (int a = 0; a < Objects.length; a++) {
    // add the set containing (Objects[a])
    for (int b = a + 1; b < Objects.length; b++) {
        // add the set containing (Objects[a], Objects[b])
        for (int c = b + 1; c < Objects.length; c++) {
            // add the set containing (Objects[a], Objects[b], Object[c])
            for (int d = c + 1; d < Objects.length; d++) {
            // add the set containing (Objects[a], Objects[b], Object[c], Object[d])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah, that does look like it will work. I'll try it out when I get back to my computer.

Comment: Nope. This does not produce any sub-sets at all, in fact it produces sets with more than 4 elements.

Comment: I think you may have misinterpreted what my comments mean. I tried to clarify them. Basically each comment produces one set to add to the list of sets (or to process immediately, if you don't need to store them).

Answer (score 2):

If you can use [Google Guava library](https://github.com/google/guava), then using [`Sets.powerSet`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#powerSet(java.util.Set)) method and Java 8 will work:

```
Set<Integer> original = ...;
Set<Set<Integer>> result = 
    Sets.powerSet(original).stream()
        .filter(s -> s.size() <= 4)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

As stated in the linked docs, this works as long as the original set's size is less than or equal to 30. It's also worth mentioning the following note:

> Performance notes: while the power set of a set with size n is of size 2^n, its memory usage is only O(n). When the power set is constructed, the input set is merely copied. Only as the power set is iterated are the individual subsets created, and these subsets themselves occupy only a small constant amount of memory.

Comment: Nice. I'm done with what I was doing, but this library looks cool, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 2):

Just out of curiosity, I came up with an algorithm that uses bit patterns and is not (theoretically) tied to a maximum of 4 objects in each subset. The following Java code is limited to 30 objects due to the size of `int`s (32bit), though. I know this approach results in a pretty lame runtime complexity of O(2^n) (I would not recommend it for production), but I kind of like the idea :-)

```
int minSize = 0; // min subset size
int maxSize = 4; // max subset size
int[] a = IntStream.range(0, 30).toArray(); // generate test data

// maximum number of subsets 2^n
int nSubsets = 1 << a.length;
// subsets container
// initial size could be calculated e.g.:
// 30!/(4!*26!) + 30!/(3!*27!) + ... + 1
List<int[]> subsets = new ArrayList<>();
// iterate through all possible patterns 0..2^n
for (int mask = 0; mask < nSubsets; mask++) {
    // bitCount should be very fast on most cpus i think
    int bitCount = Long.bitCount(mask);
    if (bitCount >= minSize && bitCount <= maxSize) {
        int[] subset = new int[bitCount];
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            // add element if bit is set at i
            if ((mask & (1 << i)) != 0) {
                subset[j++] = a[i];
            }
        }
        subsets.add(subset);
    }
}
```

Comment: any idea how this could scale up to more than 30 objects?

Comment: you could use a `long` (64bit) instead of an `int` (32bit) for the calculation of the number of subsets for `n` elements. that would result in a total of 62 elements supported in your original list. haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 0):

I made a rather unorthodox solution to this...

```
// setOfSets = a set of sets
for (int a = 0; a < Objects.length; a++) {
    for (int b = a; b < Objects.length; b++) {
        for (int c = b; c < Objects.length; c++) {
            for (int d = c; d < Objects.length; d++) {
                // s = new Set
                // add Objects[a, b, c, d] to s
                // add s to setOfSets
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's not very a very smart solution, but it works.

Comment: How does that add any sets with less than 4 objects?

Comment: @JoachimSauer First iteration will try to add objects[0] four times into s (and then s into setOfSets), so that's less than 4 objects. The second iteration will add [objects[0], objects[1]], then [objects[0], objects[2]] and so on.
Only reason I also add s to setOfSets is because a lot of iterations will produce the same set of objects (i.e. a=0, b=0, c=1, d=1 will produce the same set as a=0, b=1,c=0, d=0), which is why this solution isn't exactly smart, but does the job nontheless.